# web-socket.js and WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am trying to do a web socket implementaton for browser. Firefox, Chrome works great, but when i try in IE, it creates the socket object but never calls the timer.

```
WebSocket = function(url, protocol, proxyHost, proxyPort, headers) {
var self = this;
self.__id = WebSocket.__nextId++;

WebSocket.__instances[self.__id] = self;
self.readyState = WebSocket.CONNECTING;
self.bufferedAmount = 0;
self.__events = {};

// Uses setTimeout() to make sure __createFlash() runs after the caller sets ws.onopen etc.
// Otherwise, when onopen fires immediately, onopen is called before it is set.
setTimeout(function() {
    WebSocket.__addTask(function() {
      WebSocket.__flash.create(
          self.__id, url, protocol, proxyHost || null, proxyPort || 0, headers || null);
      });
    }, 0);
};
```

What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you talking about ?
What websocket library are you using ?

Web sockets are not supported by older version of IE. I think you need to use long polling instead of websockets for those older browsers...

If your using this : https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js 
It's stated in the Documentation :

> It should work on: Google Chrome 4 or
>   later (just uses native
>   implementation) Firefox 3.x, 4.x,
>   Internet Explorer 8, 9 + Flash Player
>   10 or later It may or may not work on
>   other browsers such as Safari, Opera
>   or IE 6. Patch for these browsers are
>   appreciated, but I will not work on
>   fixing issues specific to these
>   browsers by myself.

Comment: thanks, i am using IE8 + flash player 10.2. Ideally this function inside setTimeout should have been called, when i put a breakpoint, it is not hit !

Comment: i think i am closing into it. I guess JS calls flash to give it a valid WebSocket, and flash asks my websocket server ip on port 846 for a policy file. As it is not getting that, it is not getting a valid WebSocket object. is there any example how to serve this policy file to flash ?

Comment: Have a look here : http://www.lightsphere.com/dev/articles/flash_socket_policy.html

Comment: i wrote a simple program to listen on port 843 to see what is coming from the client, i did not even get a connection ! how to debug in debug version of flash player ?